# Graph of $x^{(2/3)}$

Tags: graphing-functions, exponentiation, radicals

While examining the basics of basics of math, thinking about it non-conventionally, I stumbled upon the following dilemma:

When given a function:
$$f(x) = \left(\sqrt[3]{x}\right)^2$$

Why does [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) draw 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPHTR.png)?

Why is the real part of the function negative for $x<0$?

Isn't $f(-8)$ for example a legit, real value of 4?

Comment: Try [`cbrt(x)^2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cbrt(x)%5E2) instead. WA interpretes $(\sqrt[3]{x})^2$ as the principal (complex) value.

Comment: You are correct: WolframAlpha is skittish when it comes to fractional powers of negative numbers. To maintain full generality, it tends to use the Principal Root, which is a complex-valued function defined over complex numbers. But this generality is not appropriate when the domain is $\mathbb R$ and the exponent is a rational number with an odd denominator.

Comment: And I've always used such programs as the ultimate proof of calculations... Apparently, you can trust nothing at all.

Comment: @DartDega Trust, but verify ;-) If you enter [`x^(2/3)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(2%2F3)) in WA, the very next line displays "***Assuming the principal root $\mid$ Use  the real‐valued root instead***".

Comment: @dxiv To be honest - I didn't notice the switch. After switching it though, an interesting behavior remains - this time the domain is being narrowed down to positive numbers. Why is it so?

Comment: @DartDega I don't see that [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(2%2F3)&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22). Anyway, you can always specify the domain explicitly e.g. [`x^(2/3) for x=-10 to 10`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(2%2F3)+for+x%3D-10+to+10&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22).

Comment: @dxiv Interesting, only the mobile version of Wolfram shows a half of the graph (http://imgur.com/HrHb9ad). Anyway, I guess my question is answered. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DartDega Interesting, indeed, guess I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 1):

WolframAlpha is graphing $x^{2/3}$ using complex values. One value for $(-8)^{2/3}$ is $4$, but another value is $-2+2i\sqrt{3}$.

If you read your graph, you will see the complex value is displayed. Read the $x$-axis as your input (on the $x$-axis, go to $-8$) and read the real and imaginary parts as the output (real part is $-2$, imaginary part is about $3.5$).

Change the plot from complex-valued to real-valued, and change from principal root to real-valued root, and you'll generate the graph that you expect.